# How do I animate a block of divs inside a container automatically?

Tags: jsp, animation, css, html

I'm building a quote/testimonial display for a website and I want to be display multiple snippets inside the same container. The following image should help clarify the subsequent text ....

[image: animate divs inside container]

I have a container built into a sidebar and inside this container I've created another sub-container with a series of divs set to display:inline. What I would like to do is display div 01 and then, after a certain amount of time, have the sub-container slide to the left and display div 02 - and so on.

Then, when it get's to the end, say div 10, I'd like it to continue sliding *to the left* and again display div 01 as opposed to sliding to the right - all the way back through all of the divs to reach div 01. CSS3 animate function or JS solutions are fine - whichever might work best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in javascript with a circular carousel. [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) will do what you need if you can use jQuery by combining the auto-scrolling and circular capabilities.

```
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    auto: 2, // auto-scroll every two seconds
    wrap: 'circular'
});
```

jCarousel uses ULs instead of divs, but I'm sure there's other plugins/libraries out there that may allow you to be more flexible with your structure.

Comment: This looks great man. Thanks very much for the pointer. I'll check it out and see if it integrates well. Sure looks like it will :)

Comment: Excellent solution bro. Thanks a lot. It's a simple matter to put a div with all it's associated formatting into an <li> instead of just an image. Sweet.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the items in a div like so and repeat the first item last:

```
--------------------------
|======= ======= ======= |
||div 1| |div 2| |div 1| |
|======= ======= ======= |
--------------------------
```

You can set a timer to move the left edge of the wrapper div `<inner div width>` every `<x>` seconds. Then, when you have reached the last one (which is a copy of the first), AFTER scrolling to it you simply move the entire wrapper back to a zero-left value and no one is the wiser - because it looks the same to them.

EDIT: I don't mean animate it back to square one, I mean simply set the left to zero. There would be no visual change, but you can then continue shifting left with no problems.